# After using git init, project is still not a git repository

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I am working on an android app in eclipse, and using git for version control. I am using command line git since eclipse doesn't have any good git plugins, but when I try to use any git commands from the command line, I get the error
`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`
It should be a git repo because the way I got the project onto my computer is via a fork. And even after I `git init` I get the same error. Does this have anything to do with the fact that I'm creating the project in eclipse? And how would I get the project back onto git?

Comment: What commands are you trying?

Comment: Git stuff should have nothing to do with Eclipse. You should make sure that the .git file is present in the root of the eclipse project. If you don't see one run a "git init" at the root. You will still need to add a git remote if you would like to sync to a remote repo on github or something.

Comment: _Does this have anything to do with the fact that I'm creating the project in eclipse?_ - No, you are definitely doing something wrong with the git itself. This has nothing to do with Eclipse.

Comment: I tried "git init" but even after doing that, whenever I do another git command I get the error saying it's not a git repository

Comment: Did you get any messages after `git init`?  Have you checked whether there is a .git/ directory after you do `git init`?  Do you have the permission to do this in the directory you're in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO NOT put the repository in the workspace or the workspace in a repository.

Making the root of the project the root of a repository will limit you to only ever having that one workspace project in it.

You should be using egit and at least learning the concepts of git if you want to work with it. http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Importing_projects , http://book.git-scm.com/ .

Comment: You cloned your github fork to a local location?  Where is it in relation to the workspace project?

Comment: Remove the .git folder, clone the github project somewhere else, and then use the egit wizard to import the project correctly.  If it's a new project, use egit to share it, or failing that, close Eclipse, physically move the project files, reopen Eclipse, File|Refresh and remove the "dead" project, then import it from the new location (*without* copying it).

Comment: the workspace directory is `path/to/workspace/` the project is in `path/to/workspace/project/`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the git installation. It has nothing to do with eclipse, what os are you using?